# setState with multiple GET requests using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, axios

I'm trying to fetch and list all episodes that the selected character has appeared with the Rick and Morty API, but the `episode` property returns a list of URLs ([schema](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)), which I was fetching in a loop.

The thing is, when the request is made, the `console.log` prints all objects, but the `setEpisodes` from the `setState` hook just add the last episode.

I've tried other loop strategies, but the results were always the same.

I was expecting that all episodes would be listed, but that is what I got:[image]

My `http.js` file:

```
import axios from "axios";

const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/",
  timeout: 10000,
});

export default http;
```

My `character-details` file:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import http from "../../utils/http";

const CharacterDetails = () => {
  const [character, setCharacter] = useState(null);
  const [episodes, setEpisodes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    http.get('/character/1').then((response) => {
      setCharacter(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (character) {
      character.episode.map((episodeUrl) => {
        const episodeId = getEpisodeIdFromEpisodeURL(episodeUrl);

        http.get(`/episode/${episodeId}`).then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          setEpisodes([...episodes, response.data]);
        });
      });
    }
  }, [character]);

  function getEpisodeIdFromEpisodeURL(episode) {
    const lastIndex = episode.lastIndexOf("/");
    const episodeId = episode.slice(lastIndex + 1);
    return episodeId;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {character && (
        <>
          <div>
            <img src={character.image} alt="Character photo" />
            <h3>{character.name}</h3>
          </div>
          <p>{character.status}</p>
          <p>{character.species}</p>
          <p>{character.location.name}</p>
          {episodes.map((episode) => {
            return <p key={episode.id}>Episode: {episode.name}</p>;
          })}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default CharacterDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with a simple change:

```
useEffect(() => {
  http.get(`/character/1`).then((response) => {
    setCharacter(response.data);
  });
}, []);

const fetchEpisodes = async () => {
  const episodeUrls = character.episode;
  const episodeData = [];

  for (const url of episodeUrls) {
    const response = await http.get(url);
    episodeData.push(response.data);
  }

  setEpisodes(episodeData);
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetchEpisodes();
}, [character]);
```